# orientation change Lifecycle Methods

Tags: android

**Whenever there is an orientation change what are the lifecycle methods called ?**

Please mention the lifecycle methods when there is an orientation change of an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle), when rotate the screen, the methods that been called are: `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` and then the Activity is created again and it is calls `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

[on orientation change activity destroyed and then automatically starts onCreate()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5JwV.png)